# Make an <a> element scroll on click to a <div>

Tags: jquery, html

I have been looking to solve this issue using some jQuery that I have found around here. 
I have an anchor that when clicked I want it to scroll all the way down to a div. I managed to make it scroll to the bottom of the page but this creates issues when viewing the website from mobile devices. Here is my code:

HTML

```
<a href="#locations" class="right-side-button"><p>I WANT TO CHOOSE A DIFFERENT COUNTRY</p></a>

<div id="locations" class="location-content">
        <h2 class="our-locations">Our locations worldwide</h2>
        <some content>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
//this is what I used to scroll to the bottom
//it does what it needs to but not good for mobile devices

$('.right-side-button').click(function(){
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height()}, 'slow');});





//this is the code I am using in order to scroll to div
//for some reason it is not working when I click the anchor

var locHeight = $('main-button-section').outerHeight();
 $('.main-button-section a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var myHref = $(this).attr('href');
    var newPos = $(myHref).offset().top;
    $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: newPos-locHeight}, 1300);
  });
```

Comment: `$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#locations").offset().top - 150}, 'slow');});`. Adjust scroll position so it will not get at top

Comment: Your `locHeight `  is set to `$('main-button-section').outerHeight();`. You're missing a `.` there for the class selector.

Comment: @Mufi Thanks a lot, this did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do lot of jQuery. Animate to your div will work. You can adjust its height in case you don't want to stuck it at top.

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#myDiv").offset().top - 150 /*(150) is height to leave from top*/
    }, 2000);
});
```